Next step in proof for inner product
I'm working on understanding the use of the properties of inner products better. And in particular I'm trying to understand this problem (problem 1.7 from Elementary Functional Analysis by B. Maccluer):
"Let x and y be two vectors in an inner product space and set $\lambda = \langle y,y \rangle$. Show that
$\lambda[\lambda \langle x,x \rangle - |\langle x,y \rangle |^2] = \langle \lambda x - \langle x,y \rangle y, \lambda x - \langle x,y \rangle y \rangle $."
I class, we solved the first step the following way:
$ \langle \lambda x - \langle x,y \rangle y, \lambda x - \langle x,y \rangle y\rangle = \langle \lambda x, \lambda x \rangle - \langle \lambda x, \langle x,y \rangle y \rangle - \langle \langle x,y 
\rangle y,\lambda x \rangle + \langle \langle x,y \rangle y \rangle ,\langle x,y \rangle ,y \rangle $
As I understand we use the property of linearity of an inner product. And I can se how the first two terms ($\langle \lambda x, \lambda x \rangle - \langle \lambda x,\langle x,y \rangle y \rangle $) comes from linearity, but I don't understand where the last terms ($- \langle \langle x,y \rangle y,\lambda x \rangle + \langle \langle x,y 
\rangle y \rangle,\langle x,y \rangle ,y \rangle $) comes from?

Please use '\langle x, y \rangle' for $\langle x, y \rangle$.

Conjugate symmetry may be the answer you're looking for. (Then exploit linearity in the first argument)

Supposing that our inner product is linear in the left argument and conjugate symmetric, i.e.$\langle x,y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$, we then have anti-linearity in the right argument:
$$ \langle x, \lambda y+\mu z\rangle = \overline{\langle \lambda y+\mu z, x\rangle} = \overline{\lambda \langle y,x\rangle + \mu \langle z,x\rangle} = \overline{\lambda} \langle x,y\rangle + \overline{\mu}\langle x,z\rangle.   $$
Then for any vectors $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, and scalars $\kappa$, $\mu$, $\lambda$, and $\nu$, we can expand $\langle \kappa a+\mu b, \lambda c+\nu d\rangle$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\langle \kappa a+\mu b, \lambda c+\nu d\rangle &= \kappa \langle a, \lambda c + \nu d \rangle + \mu \langle b, \lambda c + \nu d\rangle & \text{by left-linearity} \\ 
&= \kappa \left(\overline{\lambda} \langle a,c\rangle +\overline{\nu} \langle a,d\rangle \right) + \mu \left(\overline{\lambda} \langle b,c\rangle +\overline{\nu} \langle b,d\rangle \right)  & \text{by anti-linearity} \\ 
&= \kappa\overline{\lambda} \langle a,c\rangle + \kappa \overline{\nu} \langle a,d\rangle + \mu \overline{\lambda} \langle b,c\rangle + \mu\overline{\nu}  \langle b,d\rangle.
\end{align*}
For your particular question, replace the scalars and vectors as appropriate.
